# how to remove files and directory in a appointed path?

Tags: cocoa

Now I want to remove some files and directory in a appointed path. such as file extension is .png and directries are named as abc , In the appointed directory maybe have some subdirectory , how to get the array of the files and directories at the appointed? and then how to remove them? I found a method:
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains                    (NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

but I thought this is a method for search the NSLibraryDirectory ,not for a appointed path, how to do ? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Read up on NSFileManager